# Poll SCM multiple repositories on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have around 10 repositories that I would like to poll. If a folder is a added in the root folder of any repo, I'd like to trigger a certain build, (the same).

I thought using the Poll SCM plugin but it requires one job per repo and it's not scalable.

Is there any clean way to do this and any plugin that would help?

EDIT: I have a job generating debian packages from folders that are in my 10 repositories (each folder corresponds to a separate package). When a new folder is added, it means a new package is.
I would like then to trigger a packaging build so developers can fetch it from our apt repository without waiting the nightly build

Comment: To make sure I understand the question correctly: You have `n` repos that you want to poll (polling in the Jenkins sense means "see if there are any new commits"), then you want to check those repos to see if a specific folder has been added (the same folder for all of them?), then, if that folder has been added, you want to trigger a single specific job?

Comment: @bto Not the same directory name, actually any folder would do

Comment: I think unfortunately the answer is going to be "there is not a clean way to do this." The normal Jenkins approach is to just run whenever there are changes and rebuild/redeploy/re-whatever as part o the job's internal logic. Maybe if we knew why you only want to trigger when there's a new folder, we can come up with something that's maybe not "clean" but at least a bit more scalable?

Comment: Thanks, I also feel this way, or I'm missing something obvious. I added some more information

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin

As per the manual:

> Enhances Pipeline plugin to handle branches better by automatically
>   grouping builds from different branches. Automatically creates a new
>   Jenkins job whenever a new branch is pushed to a source code
>   repository. Other plugins can define various branch types, e.g. a Git
>   branch, a Subversion branch, a GitHub Pull Request etc.

See this blog post for more info:https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/ "

Comment: I just tested, I don't see any poll/trigger option and description

Comment: Tried restarting Jenkins?

Comment: May be do not understand the issue.
Do you mean after installing the plug-in I suggested, you are not able to see poll/trigger option?